# How to get APO alerts?

Tags: abap, sap-apo

I have the requirement to select different SAP APO alerts (e. g. quantity or time alerts). How do I get this data? Is there a specific function module or something like this?

I already tried different data sources, e. g. method READ_ALERTS of /SAPAPO/CL_AMOALRT_MANAGER class, or function module /SAPAPO/RRP_GET_ALERTS_AMON and /SAPAPO/READ_PP_ALERTS. Nothing provides me with the correct data. Do you have an idea?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the transaction Alert monitor in APO system. Alerts are broadly defined In to 3 applications E.g DP, SNP & PPDS. In SNP/PPDS you have alerts for the under/over delivery quantity, planning requirement quantity and order delay (time) alerts. Please check these function modules
 /SAPAPO/RRP_GET_ALERTS_AMON and /SAPAPO/READ_PP_ALERTS.